# Cannot make changes to assets in rails development environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

After changing my Rails app from version 4.2.0 to 5.0.2, I can no longer make changes to assets in my rails development environment.

I looked at [Rails dev environment not updating html/css/assets even after restarting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762939/rails-dev-environment-not-updating-html-css-assets-even-after-restarting-server) and emptied my `public/assets` folder.  After emptying that (& after restarting my server and emptying my browser cache and precompiling assets again), I still had the same problem.

I then tried `$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development`, which "sort of" solved my problem -- but I have to do this and restart the server every time!

I had not made any changes to `development.rb` before this problem began.

I did `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:clean`, `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, and `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails server` and I cleared my browser cache, but my assets still won't change in the development environment.  I still have to shut off my server and to do `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development` for every change I make.

If anyone has any idea how to solve this problem, I'd much appreciate it.

EDIT: Actually, when looking at [Rails dev environment not updating html/css/assets even after restarting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762939/rails-dev-environment-not-updating-html-css-assets-even-after-restarting-server/12762970) again, in Chris Heald's answer he advised removing the entire `public/assets` folder (not just its contents).  I did that (& and also made a `public/assets_hide` folder per Max Dunn's advice) and it worked!  I'm back in business.

Comment: You don't need to precompile assets in development env

Comment: clean the assets for dev env and then clear browser cache